# run through JS object list

Tags: javascript, list, for-loop

I can't run through this list and I've tried all ways:

```
list=[{'fullName': 'doubleparty', 'name': 'double'}, {'fullName': 'runtime', 'name': 'run'}, }];

for (var i in list) {}
```

I tried to parse it to JSON but the simple quotes are not accepted ( I think )

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `for (var i in list) ` will work. What's the problem?

Comment: Single quotes are not allowed in JSON, but luckily you're writing in JavaScript and JavaScript thinks it's fine.

Comment: The bucle run a lot of loops(huge). Maybe the total letters in the list.

Comment: @user3612445  — No, it won't. At least, not with the code you've provided. Perhaps your test case doesn't actually reproduce the problem you are having. (It does have errors in it that I assumed were a transcription problem). Try creating a test case that actually demonstrates your problem.

Comment: You don't "parse to JSON" You parse JSON to an object, or stringify an object to JSON. What do you mean by "tried to parse it to JSON"? Your variable `list` is not JSON anyway, it's a POJO (plain old JavaScript object), so what is there to parse? Anyway, since this object is an array, your `for (var i in list)` will simply iterate over the elements of the array, of which there are two. (That is after you eliminate the spurious `}` towards the end, a syntax error). That **is** running through the list--what else do you want to do? You said you've "tried all ways". What other ways did you try?

Comment: @torazaburo — two, and a syntax error in the form of a trailing `, }`.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I tried to represent my code but I failed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, *there is a syntax error in your code* that prevents it from working properly, you should remove the extra `,}`:

  ```
  list=[{'fullName': 'doubleparty', 'name': 'double'}, {'fullName': 'runtime', 'name': 'run'}];
  ```
- Second, **list is an array of objects** so you have to treat it like an array:

  ```
  for(var j = 0; j < 2; j++) { // iterate throw the list array
      for (var i in list[j]) { // iterate throw the objects in list array
          alert(i);
      }
  }
  ```